# Trying to make a Discord bot play a sound when someone joins the VC

Tags: python

I would like the bot to join a voice channel when someone joins and then play a sound file.

So far I've gotten the bot to join the voice channel but it just doesn't play the sound and no errors show so I don't really know what is going wrong.

```
import discord
import audioread
from asyncio import sleep
from main import client


@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):
    path = r"https://gigachad.com.br/assets/olhaeleae.mp3"

    vc_before = before.channel
    vc_after = after.channel
    if vc_before == vc_after:
        return
    if vc_before is None:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
        with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:

            sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()

    elif vc_after is None:
        return
    else:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
        with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:
            #Start Playing
            sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()
```